# Wordpress comments are always closed in new posts?

Tags: wordpress, comments

I'm running a wordpress multi-author blog and comments are always closed when a new post is published.  I would want the default to be that comments are always open automatically. 
I think I have the right settings in 'Discussion' settings as you can see:
I can't post images coz I'm new here so let me describe the settings:

> [unselected] Attempt to notify any blogs.. 
> [selected] Allow
>   link notifications from other blogs... 
> [selected] Allow people to
>   post comments on new articles 
> [unselected] comment author must
>   fillout name and email 
> [selected] Users must be registered and
>   logged in to comment

Any tips or code alterations in wordpress you could recommend?  As you can imagine, It's annoying to have to manually switch on comments for all new posts everyday.

Answer (score 0):

`unselect` User must be registered and logged in to comment.

thats what is causing the problem.

Comment: Tried it but it didn't work.  Any new post from an author or an editor has it's comments closed by default.  I would love to have it open comments by default instead.

Comment: 'Allow people to post comment on new articles' is also checked. strange, right.  Any post by an author has its comments closed by default.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with the Wordpress cookies. Have you tried refreshing your cookie secrets? Visit http://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/ and then paste the result into your `wp-config.php` file, in place of the old secrets. Warning: everyone will have to log in again.

You might also try updating Wordpress to the latest version, using a fresh config file. It sounds like a piece of your configuration got broken; a fresh install usually fixes it.